# Is this claim true? (About the sequence $\{a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}\}$)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Suppose that $\{(a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ converges and denote with $\alpha$ its limit ($a_n>0$ for all $n$). Is it true that $\{(a_{n+1})^{\frac{1}{n}}\}$ converges to the same limit than the first sequence? Does it even converges necessarely?

I'm trying to solve a problem and, if this result happens to be true, the problem simplifies a lot. Can you give me hand with this please? Counterexamples or hints of a possible proof would be extremely useful (I've tried a lot, but I have not reached any of those).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: $$a_{n+1}^{1/n} = {\left(a_{n+1}^{1/(n+1)}\right)}^{(n+1)/n}$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, It was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Certainly if the sequence were $(a_{n+1})^{1/(n+1)}$ the sequence would converge to the same value, call it $L$, as the original sequence. Now let's write $$(a_{n+1})^{1/n}=((a_{n+1})^{1/(n+1)})^{1+\frac{1}{n}}.$$

This converges to the same value as the orginal series, since $1+1/n$ converges to $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've choosen Adhvaitha's answer as accepted since he answered first, but I've used your anwser too.

Comment: You are free to accept any answer you like. I am just glad your got an answer to your question. Up votes are always welcome too :)

Comment: Thanks! As I've said, your answer was very useful for me too. :)